# How to integrate google reviews into the page?

Tags: plugin, extensions, google

I am searching for a option to integrate Google Reviews in Joomla so that:

- I can show the reviews easily to vistors of the page (e.g. in a module)
- I can give google these review to show in the search results

is where any good plugin to solve that issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Using a Joomla Extension**

There are currently very few Joomla extensions that help with displaying Google Reviews. Examples include [Google Business Reviews](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/google-business-reviews) (from €34.95) and [Google Reviews Pro](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/google-reviews-pro) (from $39.00).

**A Quick Option**

Another free quick option, not involving a Google API key, is to manually recreate a few positive reviews with appropriate links for website visitors to read more reviews / leave a new review. You can see an example on Kamron Brooks website at https://skyspider.com.au/#reviews

You can add a "**Show More Reviews**" button to link directly to the reviews page on Google. For a direct link to the reviews, search for your business in Google, click on the "View all Google reviews" link in the business details on the right hand side of the page and use the url in the address bar.

You can also add a "**Write a Review**" button to make it easier for website visitors to leave you a Google review. To obtain the correct link, log in to Google, search for your business in Google and click on the "Get more reviews" in the business details on the right hand side of the page to reveal the link.